# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets in accuracy_score

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am learning with neural networks, from boston_Housing and I get an error that I don't know what it means.

```
from keras.datasets import boston_housing
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = boston_housing.load_data()


neural_model = Sequential([
    Dense(2, input_shape=(13,), activation="relu"),
    Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

neural_model.summary()

neural_model.compile(SGD(lr = .003), "binary_crossentropy", \
                     metrics=["accuracy"])

np.random.seed(0)
run_hist_1 = neural_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40,\
                              validation_data=(x_test, y_test), \
                              verbose=True, shuffle=False)

print("Training neural network...\n")

print('Accuracy over training data is ', \
      accuracy_score(y_train, neural_model.predict_classes(x_train))

print('Accuracy over testing data is ', \
      accuracy_score(y_test, neural_model.predict_classes(x_test)))

conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, neural_model.predict_classes(x_test))
print(conf_matrix)
```

I get this error:

```
Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets at
this point print('Accuracy over testing data is ', \
---> 29       accuracy_score(y_test, neural_model.predict_classes(x_test)))
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do `classification` on a dataset/task which is fit for regression. Your targets (y_train and y_test) are continuous values, and not discrete categories. The complete method needs correction.

1. Final Dense layer activation should be changed from `sigmoid` to `linear` or `relu`
2. In the `compile` function, `loss` should be `mse`
3. metrics can be left empty or be set to `mae` or `mse` again.
4. Accuracy and confusion matrix cannot be used for evaluation

You should check out some fundamental topics in machine learning and neural networks, specially difference between logistic and linear regression.